# How to add a filter/query/condition in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotting, plotly

I want to add a condition to the column where `attractionName.value_counts() >=165`. How can I add a query/filter/condition to a DataFrame before I plot the data.

```
fig = px.bar(rwgor, x="attractionName", y="attraction score summary", color="attraction score summary", title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

With the above code I can plot all values in the column `attractionName`. I only want to plot values whose value_counts() is grater than 165.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DataFrame is **rwgor**, you need to filter it like this:

```
rwgor = rwgor.loc[rwgor.attractionName >=165]
fig = px.bar(rwgor, x="attractionName", y="attraction score summary", color="attraction score summary", title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

or

```
fig = px.bar(rwgor.loc[rwgor.attractionName >=165], x="attractionName", y="attraction score summary", color="attraction score summary", title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

Finally, note that I used rwgor.attractionName >=165 and **not** rwgor.attractionName.**value_counts()** >=165, according your plot description.